# How I can deploy all reports to SSRS using RS.exe

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, rs.exe

Following the below article, I was able to deploy one report to SSRS thought command line:

[sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-rsexe-utility](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3255/sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-rsexe-utility/)

What I should modify in order to deploy all the reports in my folder? the VB.NET file or RS.exe command arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was given here SQL expert:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/345731/rsexe-script-to-deploy-all-reports-from-one-folder.html